# SubSonic 2.2 Installation Instructions?

Tags: subsonic

Just wondering if anyone can point me in the directions for the SubSonic 2.2 installation instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_2.x

Comment: Legend thanks.. Wanting to use v3 but really struggling with getting it working, this works perfectly! Keep up the amazing work matey, can't even imagine how much work has gone into this amazing tool.

Comment: To Rob Conery: Where are those 3 nice videos that you had in SubSonic page to install and use SubSonic 2.x? I do miss them!

Comment: @Rob Conery. It seems that the link no longer working. It shows the HTML source.

Answer (score 1):

There are several movies regarding installation and use :)

for **Setting up SubSonic 2.x**, [use this screencast](http://subsonicproject.com/docs/Setting_up_SubSonic_2.x) from Rob :)

---

To **Rob Conery**: Where are those **3 nice videos** that you had in SubSonic page to install and use SubSonic 2.x? I do miss them!

Comment: 2 of them don't apply and the other is above.

Comment: I do miss those ones with the use :( 
was a nice place to gather all info on use SubSonic :)

Answer (score 1):

**SubSonic 2.2**

```
<configSections>
    <section name="SubSonicService" type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="kiss" connectionString ="Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS; Database=kiss; UID=sa; PWD=sa;" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <SubSonicService defaultProvider="kiss">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="kiss" type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic" connectionStringName="kiss" generatedNamespace="kiss.DataAccessLayer"/>
    </providers>
  </SubSonicService>
```

**Tools | External Tools:**

```
SubSonic DAL
C:\Program Files\SubSonic\SubSonic 2.2 Final\SubCommander\sonic.exe
generate /out App_Code\Generated
$(ProjectDir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Download and run the 2.1 installer, then copy the files from the 2.2 download into the 2.1 install location.